# Null Reference Exception which switching between tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

In my controller, I have something like this:

```
 [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

    int treatmentId = (int)UserSession.GetValue(StateNameEnum.ID, "TreatmentID");

    List<int> Ids = db.frames.Where(f => f.PlanId == treatmentId).Select(f => f.Id).ToList();
        int Id = Ids[0];

    PlanViewModel vm = new PlanViewModel();  

    case_info info = db.info.Where(r => r.Id == Id && r.LocationId ==     (int)LocationEnum.Proximal).Select(r => r).First();

    if (info.IsReference == 1)
    {
        vm.ReferenceId = ReferenceTypeEnum.Proximal.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        vm.ReferenceId = ReferenceTypeEnum.Distal.ToString();
    }
    return PartialView(vm);

    }
```

and in my view I have this code:

```
@if (Model.ReferenceId == "Proximal") //Getting Null Reference Exception here
{
    <span class="circle Plan-circle" style="background-color: rgb(255,0,0)"></span>
}
else if (Model.ReferenceId == "Distal")
{
    <span class="circle Plan-circle" style="background-color: rgb(0,0,255)"></span>
}
```

In my view, that's the kind of logic I want to use to check if the ReferenceId is set to a specific string or not and change the view based on that value from the model.

However, I noticed while the above works sometimes, I noticed I get a null exception when switching between tabs. I wonder why my model is null and if it makes sense how I'm grabbing the logic from the controller?

Using what I have set up in the controller, how can I check for when the model is set to a specific value in the view?

EDIT:

Js file that's called when switching tabs:

```
  ToggleTabSwitch: function (data) {

            var tabSelector = $('#tab-selector'); // any id you input in the first div
            tabSelector.on('click', '.newUI-left-selector', function () {
                $(this).removeClass('-newUI-left-selector');
                $(this).addClass('newUI-toggled-left-selector');

                //left selector toggled.
                $.ajax({
                    url: BrowserSide.Url.getFullUrl("DeformityPlanning/LoadDPPartialView"),
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#selector-render').html(result);

                        BrowserSide.Plan.enableButtons();

                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        BrowserSide.AjaxLog.HandleAjaxCallFail(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown, "ajax error in Plan.js Load DP_form view", "");
                    }
                });

                var rightToggedSelector = $('.newUI-toggled-right-selector');
                if (rightToggedSelector.length > 0) {
                    rightToggedSelector.removeClass('newUI-toggled-right-selector');
                    rightToggedSelector.addClass('newUI-right-selector');
                }
            });

            tabSelector.on('click', '.newUI-right-selector', function () {
                $(this).removeClass('newUI-right-selector');
                $(this).addClass('newUI-toggled-right-selector');

                // right selector toggled

                $.ajax({
                    url: BrowserSide.Url.getFullUrl("DeformityPlanning/LoadAPPartialView"),
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#selector-render').html(result);
                        btnList = $("button[data-val-btnName]");
                        BrowserSide.Plan.enableButtons();

                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        BrowserSide.AjaxLog.HandleAjaxCallFail(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown, "ajax error in Plan.js Load DP_formtwo view", "");
                    }
                });

                var rightToggedSelector = $('.newUI-toggled-left-selector');
                if (rightToggedSelector.length > 0) {
                    rightToggedSelector.removeClass('newUI-toggled-left-selector');
                    rightToggedSelector.addClass('newUI-left-selector');
                }
            });
        }
```

How I return the partial views in controller:

```
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public ActionResult LoadDPPartialView()
    {
        return PartialView("DP_form");
    }

    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public ActionResult LoadAPPartialView()
    {
        List<PlanViewModel.PlanViewParam> newItem = new List<PlanViewModel.PlanViewParam>();

        return PartialView("DP_formtwo");
    }
```

EDIT #2:

Attempt to fixing the problem:

```
private void GetReferenceId()
    {

        int treatmentId = (int)UserSession.GetValue(StateNameEnum.ID, "TreatmentID");

        PlanViewModel vm = new PlanViewModel();

        List<int> Ids = db.frames.Where(f => f.PlanId == treatmentId).Select(f => f.Id).ToList();
        int Id = Ids[0];

         case_info info = db.info.Where(r => r.Id == Id && r.LocationId == (int)LocationEnum.Proximal).Select(r => r).First();

        if (info.IsReference == 1)
        {
            vm.ReferenceId = ReferenceTypeEnum.Proximal.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            vm.ReferenceId = ReferenceTypeEnum.Distal.ToString();
        }
    }

    public ActionResult LoadDPPartialView()
    {
            GetReferenceId();
            return PartialView("DP_form");
    }
```

Comment: There are probably 100 different ways to implement "tabs" in MVC.  You'll need to be more specific before anyone can make even a guess at what is wrong.  Debugger will help you determine what code path is not setting the model properly during the request.  Need to step through your code and make sure it's being populated.

Comment: Well, it says the Model is null but I have no idea where to begin as to why it could be null? How do fix a null model? The only thing I can think of is starting from scratch and wondering seeing how I set up the controller, where can I go from there? How do I check if my model is equal to a certain value?

Comment: Model gets passed to the view from the Controller action method.  `View("Something")` will cause a null model because you didn't pass the model via `View("Soemthing", someModel)`.  You should start with figuring out how your tabs work.  Use browser debugger to view the network request that is made when you click a tab, use that URL to determine what action is being called, then put a breakpoint in that controller and run under debugging so you can step through the controller line by line and make sure the model is being populated.

Comment: It looks like there's an Id property or parameter from the right hand side of `r.Id == Id`. Show where that comes from.  There are no parameters in your index action. If this ID were null on the second request it would create an issue.

Comment: I don't think it's the id. See edit.

Comment: "DeformityPlanning/LoadAPPartialView" This points to the Index action you posted?  It looks like a different action...

Comment: It is a different action. It points to the action I posted in the edit... :S public ActionResult LoadAPPartialView()
    {
        List<PlanViewModel.PlanViewParam> newItem = new List<PlanViewModel.PlanViewParam>();

        return PartialView("DP_formtwo");
    }

Comment: It points to the action that returns the partial view and not the index() of the controller. So I think that has something to do with it.

Comment: Yep, `return PartialView("DP_form");` doesn't provide a model to the View, so the view model will be null.

Comment: So should I move out the logic from the index()  to the other action method? How would I fix this?

Comment: I'd probably factor out the code that retrieves the data and populates the model into a private method, so that it can be called from all the actions that need that model.  Commonly in an onion architecture you'd have another layer/tier that you retrieve model data from so that similar queries can be reused across multiple actions.

Comment: I separated out the logic and put it into a private method, then called the private method in LoadDPPartialView() but it still returns a null model??? Very strange.... Maybe I'm setting the wrong model? I have no idea.

Comment: You're still not passing the model to the view.  Again, the model gets to the view via passing it such as `PartialView("someview", someModel)`. If you don't pass the model then `PartialView("someview")` will result in null model.  Your private method needs to return the vm to the caller, then the caller can pass it to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic you show for your Razor/CSHTML seems fine.  **It's very specialized to display/presentation since it's just choosing a color, so IMO it's appropriate in the view.**  Nothing that I would call business logic.

Although it could be made more DRY with a helper function of something like `ReferenceTypeToRgbColor` and use that in the style or even better emit a class and put your style in CSS.   I'd also probably suggest using an enum or constants instead of string "Proximal", but that's another story.

```
@function string CircleTypeToCssClass(string circleType)
{ 
    if (circleType == "Proximal")
    {
        return "proximal-circle";
    }
    else if (circleType == "Distal")
    {
         return "distal-circle";
    } 
    else 
       return "";
}

<span class="circle Plan-circle @(CircleTypeToCssClass(Model.ReferenceId))"></span>
```

Comment: That makes me wonder, should I be returning the ReferenceId in the controller after 'vm.ReferenceId = ReferenceTypeEnum.Proximal.ToString(); return ReferenceId;' kind of like that?

Comment: @KalaJ I don't have the full picture of your code to say for sure, but usually the pattern would be something like `vm.ReferenceId = ReferenceTypeEnum.Proximal.ToString(); return View("MyViewName", vm);`

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look :) EDIT: opps, one more thing, I am using partial views... so after a bunch of code, I am returning the parameters using "return PartialView(vm);" Now, the thing is the views for the tabs are two separate views. view1.cshtml for tab1 and view2.cshtml for tab2. When I load tab1, my models are populated, etc.. When I go to tab2 and then back to tab1, my model is then null.

Comment: @KalaJ We can only guess without seeing your controller actions and views.

Comment: I noticed something strange though, I noticed when I go to tab2 then back to tab1, the Index() that is supposed to return partialview never gets called. That is, the partial view is never returned, so the model is null. But the view is still rendered(perhaps a cache of the view??). Not sure why Index() doesn't get called again when switching between tabs. Should I move my model check outside of the Index()?

Comment: @KalaJ Need to show how your tabs are declared in razor, and what your controller actions look like.  If you want more help, update your question.  Otherwise I'm just guessing in the dark.

Comment: I'll update with tab code snippet (since there's a lot of code). But see edited post. I updated my controller code from last time

Answer (score 0):

Are sure that your exception comes from the Razor view and not from the controller?

```
case_info info = db.info.Where(r => r.Id == Id && r.LocationId ==     (int)LocationEnum.Proximal).Select(r => r).First();
```

**.First()** will throw an exception, if the resultset is empty. Try using **.FirstOrDefault()** instead

Comment: The exception is thrown at the line Model.ReferenceId above, in which the model is null. I'll see if .FirstOrDefault() does anything

Comment: Nope, it's not the controller, it's the razor view :( Still get null exception

Comment: I think the problem comes from your controller logic. I see that you are usinf if --> else to set the ReferenceId on the model. Are you sure that this always sets a value?